# Weird application document's directory being returned

Tags: ios, swift

So I have this:

```
private static func getSessionCookie() -> String? {
    let documentsDirectory = applicationDocumentsDirectory()!.path!
    let filePath = "\\" + documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString(sessionCookieFileName)
    var error: NSError?

    return String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
}

private static func setSessionCookie(newSessionCookie: String) {
    let documentsDirectory = applicationDocumentsDirectory()!.path!
    let filePath = "\\" + documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString(sessionCookieFileName)
    var error: NSError?

    newSessionCookie.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
}
```

The setter works great, it gets the right documents directory and creates the right file path. Now the getter returns some weird value for the applicationDocumentsDirectory call: "\xd0\xb0K7".

What's going on? Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE Added more code to help clarify the question**

```
let sessionCookieFileName = "sessionCookie.txt"

func applicationDocumentsDirectory() -> NSURL? {
    return NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).last as? NSURL

}
```

Comment: you getter does not return the `Documents` folder's path, but a `String` object which inited from a file. what is your question here?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. My question is, the getter isn't returning the right String because the Documents folder's path isn't right.

Comment: what is the value of the `sessionCookieFileName`? what is the implementation of the `applicationDocumentsDirectory()` method?

Comment: what is the actual `filePath` (if you log it to the console) in case of _set_ and in case of _get_? can you please add those values to your OP as well?

Comment: filePath in setter never worked me, which throws error path doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you deleting the previous session before setting newer? And can you use tmp instead of document directory?

Comment: Ok so I ended up trying a different approach (saving the session id on keychain, which is more secure). When I have some time, I'll try to update this question with the requests and test some of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You may be seeing a debugger artifact.   Swift tends to reorder instructions or get the breakpoints at a wrong location.   If you see the garbage values you describe, try stepping through the code and verifying that the set lines actually get executed.

This is one of those fun 'unrelated bugs' that might, or might not, be what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\\`

`let filePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString(sessionCookieFileName)`

Should work.. Tested in Playground